# How to use Trim Function in Vertica to update string

Tags: sql, trim, vertica

```
update table1
set split_part(client_info,':',9)=Trim(split_part(client_info,':',9))
where lm_id=122344556 and record_id=11111
```

I am tring to update Client_info string to remove spaces from one of the values in string but getting syntax error at "(".
I have tried but not able to figure out where I am missing this bracket.

Comment: you can only set a hole column, not a part of it, so first try to  remove the spaces in a select query and use that on the right side

Comment: client_info is the string separated with ":" and I want to just update some part of it . 
    update table1
    set split_part(client_info,':',9)=(select Trim(split_part(client_info,':',9)) from table1 
    where lm_id=122344556 and record_id=11111) I tried this but getting same error

Comment: Some part is often difficult, because of regular expression or splitting and th concatenation please add some data that you have maybe someone can help with that. Like I said try it in a select till it gives you the correct answer

Comment: Thanks following worked for 
update table1
set client_info= Replace(client_info,split_part(client_info,':',9),trim(split_part(client_info,':',9)))
wherelm_id=122344556 and record_id=11111

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE table1
  SET client_info = REGEXP_REPLACE(client_info,' *:',':',1,9)
;
```

Or better, if you update all rows of the table, do:

Create a copy of `table1` using `COPY_TABLE()` (check our documentation)

Truncate `table1`.

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT col1,col2, ...,coln, REGEXP_REPLACE(client_info,' *:',':',1,9),colnplus1,...,collast 
FROM the_copy;
```